# Variable declaration syntax error in the for next loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, variables, declaration

Following code is working properly.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Dictionary1 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary2 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary3 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary4 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary5 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    Dictionary1.Add("George", "36")
    Dictionary2.Add("George", "36")
    Dictionary3.Add("George", "36")
    Dictionary4.Add("George", "36")
    Dictionary5.Add("George", "36")
End Sub
```

I have tried to shorten the above code like the below code via for next loop.

But the below code gives me an error.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Dictionary1 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary2 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary3 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary4 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary5 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        ("Dictionary" & i).Add("George", "36")
    Next
End Sub
```

So, how can I solve the following error?

[image: Error in the picture]

Comment: _("Dictionary" & i)_  creates a string, why do you expect it to be the name of a variable?

Comment: @Steve  I just want to shorten that code. Do you know any solution?

Comment: Could you maybe explain exactly what you’re trying to achieve for some context?

Comment: @Hursey My original code consist of 100 lines of code. I want to shorten 100 lines of code to 3 lines of code via for next loop.

Comment: Would a dictionary of dictionary be workable?

Comment: @Hursey I just want the second code works like the first code which I have posted.

Comment: You need to create an array of your dictionaries and add them to the array. Then you can loop over the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of Dictionary

```
    Dim Dictionary1 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary2 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary3 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary4 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim Dictionary5 As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    Dim ds As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
    ds.Add(Dictionary1)
    ds.Add(Dictionary2)
    ds.Add(Dictionary3)
    ds.Add(Dictionary4)
    ds.Add(Dictionary5)

    For Each d As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) In ds
        d.Add("George", 37)
    Next
```